# How can I make text in Android Studio readable?

Tags: xubuntu, android, fonts, ubuntu-for-android, linux-headers

I have installed Android Studio in Ubuntu 17.4 but it seems to use a very bad font. It does not show most characters at all, instead showing tiny boxes as though they were characters the font doesn't provide.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio, with numerous characters in the UI shown as rectangular boxes.]

Comment: DId you install any new themes recently on your system?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to an unrecognized font.

See the below image for a guide as to how to change the font.

[image: Steps]]

Or, in text:

1. In Android Studio, go to **File** > **Settings**
2. In Settings, go to **Appearance and Behavior**
3. Select the **Appearance** sub-menu
4. Check the **`Override default fonts`** option.
5. Set your overridden font to `Ubuntu` with size 15 (or whatever you prefer)